# jQuery: get object number in the DOM among the list of objects with the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object

Suppose I have 
`$('.mybutton').length==6` on the page which means I have six objects with class `.mybutton` on the page.

```
$('.mybutton').on('click',function(){
//one of 6 buttons was clicked
});
```

If I type `$('.mybutton')` , six objects will be displayed in some order.

The question is: how to get the objects' number?

Let's say if there are 6 objects and the second object of that list was clicked, I need to make some manipulations with 5th object.

Comment: I'd suggest [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/), but I'm not quite sure what you're asking.

Comment: ... and  [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: within the click event you can write  var index = $.inArray( $this,$('.mybutton') ); which will return u the index

Comment: You'd be far better off if your HTML included explicit attributes to indicate the relationships between elements.

Comment: @MukeshAgarwal `$('.mybutton').index(this)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Does `index()` works?**

```
$('.mybutton').on('click',function(){
    console.info("button", $(this).index(), "was clicked");
});
```

It should work if the elements are siblings, as explained in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/index/), `If we omit the argument, .index() will return the position of the first element within the set of matched elements in relation to its siblings`.
Check the example bellow:

```js
$(".button").on("click", function() {
  $("#results").html("You've clicked on the element with the index " + $(this).index());
});
```

```css
.button {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="button">Example 0</div>
  <div class="button">Example 1</div>
  <div class="button">Example 2</div>
  <div class="button">Example 3</div>
  <div class="button">Example 4</div>
</div>
<div><b>Results:</b>
</div>
<div id="results"></div>
```

**If for some odd reason that doesn't work, a quick solution would be.....**

(Note that this may not be the best solution according to the standarts / performance wise)

```
$('.mybutton').each(function(i) {
    $(this).on('click',function(){
        console.info("button", i, "was clicked");
    });
});
```

**But if index really doesn't work you should add a class, id, data-argument - anything that allows us to distinguish the item - to the button you want to modify.**

For instance, let's assume you add a class `special-modifier` to the 5th button, you would do something like:

```
$('.mybutton').on('click',function(){
    if($(this).is(".special-modifier")) {
        console.info("special modifier button was clicked");
    }
});
```

Comment: No, that won't work - `.index()` works based on the jQuery object involved, so when you make a new one with `$(this)` they'll all have index zero. (The second code sample will probably work though.)

Comment: Well @Pointy that's not actually true, it seems to use the HTML siblings rather than the "jQuery object involved" - I made an example to demonstrate this at http://jsfiddle.net/bbk2tjv5/ - If the elements are all siblings then the index technique will work. If you check the docs at http://api.jquery.com/index/ you will find that `If we omit the argument, .index() will return the position of the first element within the set of matched elements in relation to its siblings` - so calling `.index()` on the button will work no matter of the context it was called - as long as they are all siblings :)

Comment: Not a problem @Pointy and hey, if you had that "question" other persons looking at this in the future may think the same thing, I'll update my answer accordingly :) Thanks!